# OpenMP 4.0 task dependencies of a pointer (OmpSs style)

Tags: dependencies, task, openmp

I want to specify a `#pragma omp task depend(...)` clause on a variable reference through a pointer. This is possible in [OmpSs](https://pm.bsc.es/ompss) and looks like:

```
#pragma omp task in(*var1) out(*var2)
```

Basically this is what I want to do in OpenMP 4.0, but the following code:

```
#pragma omp task depend(in: *var1) depend(out: *var2)
```

produces the following error :

```
error: expected identifier before ‘*’ token
    #pragma omp task depend(in: *var1) depend(out: *var2)
```

How can this be done in OpenMP 4.0?

Comment: One thing I always wondered about OmpSs is: how can they claim to extend OpenMP if they don't support `parallel` construct?

Comment: @Massimiliano, from the OmpSs specification: _"The most notable difference from OmpSs to OpenMP is the absence of the parallel clause in order to specify where a parallel region starts and ends. This clause is required in OpenMP because it uses a fork-join execution model where the user must specify when parallelism starts and ends. OmpSs uses the model implemented by StarSs where parallelism is implicitly created when the application starts."_ It's more of an evolution than an extension in the usual sense.

Comment: OpenMP 4.0 is not my department but it might be possible to use array sections instead, e.g. `depend(in: var1[:1]) depend(out: var2[:1])`.

Comment: @HristoIliev I agree with your interpretation, but the quoting I usually find when reading about it is _"... our objective is to extend OpenMP with new directives to support asynchronous parallelism and heterogeneity (devices like GPUs)."_ Just to clarify: I quite like the project, but I wonder out of curiosity why they stress _extend_ when OpenMP compliant code is not granted to work

Comment: @Massimiliano, I guess what they mean is they extend the _OpenMP model_ and not the _OpenMP specification_. Or they simply take a very arbitrary interpretation of what "extension" means :)

Comment: @HristoIliev Fair enough :)

Comment: @HristoIliev Sure they meant to extend the OpenMP model, but they could still do it supporting the `parallel` construct

Answer (score 3):

As per [Hristo Iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374437/hristo-iliev)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144841/openmp-4-0-task-dependencies-of-a-pointer-ompss-style#comment-37281820), the correct workaround is to consider your pointers to be arrays of size 1 :

```
#pragma omp task depend(in: var1[:1]) depend(out: var2[:1])
```

The array section syntax `arr[lower bound : length]` allowed in `depend` pragmas sets `lower bound` to 0 if omitted, and `length` to the array size if omitted (which is thus not permitted for pointer types).